# pWnd read access violation on Windows version 20H2

Tags: c++, nullpointerexception, mfc, windows-10

I am running into a very strange issue with my mfc c++ program on newer Windows 10 builds. Specifically 20H2 (Build 19042).

When launching a specific dialog from my main menu PCs running this OS build crash silently, without warning.

I have gained access to dump files and determined the issue to be
"Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation. pWnd -> was 0x33312E" with exception code 0xC0000005

This was thrown inside of wincore.cpp on line 265

```
IResult = pWnd->WindowProc(nMsg, wParam, lParam);
```

Looking at the disassembly for this line it fails here...

```
    0053A92C mov  eax,dword ptr [pWnd] (pWnd is 0x0019f4a4)
    0053A92F mov  ecx,dword ptr [eax] (eax is 0x0019f4a4)
(ecx is 0x0033312E) 
    0053A931 mov  edx,dword ptr [ecx+11Ch] (Unhandled exception here)
```

Call stack looks like this.

```
Program.exe!AfxCallWndProc(CWnd* pWnd, HWND__* hand, unsigned int nMsg, unsigned int wParam, long iParam) line 265
Program.exe!AfxWndProc(HWND__* hWnd, unsigned int nMsg, unsigned int wParam,long iParam) line 418
user32.dll!__InternalCallWinProc@20()
user32.dll!UserCallWinProcCheckWow()
user32.dll!DispatchClientMessage()
user32.dll!___fnDWORD@4()
ntdll.dll!_KiUserCallbackDispatcher@12()
Program.exe!CWND::UpdateWindow() line 106
Program.exe!CWND::RunModalLoop(unsigned long dwFlags) line 4632
Program.exe!CWND::CreateRunDlgIndirect(const DLGTEMPLATE * lpDialogTemplate, CWnd* pParentWnd, HINSTANCE__ * hInst) line 470
Program.exe!CDialog::DoModal() line 633
Program.exe!CMainDlg::OnDeviceButton() line 1271
```

Here is the code in OnDeviceButton()

```
Void CMainDlg::OnDeviceButton()
{
    CDevice device;
    device.deviceType = 7;
    device.DoModal();
}
```

Here is code from CDevice

```
BOOL CDevice::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();
      
    CloseCPC();
      
    deviceList.SetExtendedStyle(LVS_EX_GRIDLINES | LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);
    
    deviceList.InsertVolumn(0, _T("Device"), LVCFMT_LEFT, 150);
    
    deviceList.InsertColumn(1, _T("Software Version"), LVCFMT_CENTER. 100);
    
    deviceList.InsertItem(0, _T("BRTB"));
    
    SetupVersionTree();
    
    SetTimer(1,1,NULL);
    
    Sleep(20);
    
    return TRUE;
}

Void CDevice::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{
    If(nODEvent == 1)
    {
        KillTimer(1);
        If(CPC_handle == -1)
        {
            InitCPC(7,this);
        }
        If(firstPass)
        {
            GetVersion();
        }
        SetTimer(1,10000,NULL);
    }
}
```

Any ideas? I've run through about everything I can think of for debugging besides submitting a help ticket directly to Microsoft asking for assistance.

If there is any other information I can provide please let me know.

*Edit*
I forgot to mention "solutions" that I have found.

1. Initialization if the class object as a pointer
   CDevice* device = new CDevice();
2. A random development version which only difference is a new dialog item. (No longer crashes with this version)
3. Setting the timer up in InitDialog method after 20ms sleep.
4. Initializing two CPC msg structures in constructor.

These all individually "resolve" the issue but I cannot seem to find any patterns between these "solutions" and I can't sell them as a solution with the reason of "because it seems to fix it".

Comment: I would start with deleting everything from your `CDevice::OnInitDialog()`, to make sure you still have a crash.

Comment: So something that was supposed to be a pointer stored at pWnd+11Ch contained 0x33312E instead. Which in ASCII is `".13"`. Buffer overrun perhaps? That's all that can be said given the info provided.

Comment: rustyx. Now that you mention it. We are performing a CAN write over a bus in the GetVersion function. The value that is returned is 33 31 2e 32. Very interesting, I think your theory of a buffer overrun may not be too off. Although it is still odd that this only happens on the this new OS build...

Comment: Is this a UNICODE OR MBCS application?

Comment: @IronCoder99899 When I've encountered a bug like this that only happens... usually was a bug all along and I just got lucky. Vlad is giving sound advice. Comment away everything in OnInitDialog() and verify it doesn't crash. Add back lines until it does. If it starts faulting again after a call to a function of yours, then do the same in that funcion--paring back and then adding until it crashes again.

Comment: [Set data breakpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints#BKMK_set_a_data_breakpoint_native_cplusplus).

Comment: [offtopic] Whoever invented the name `CAN bus` should be forced to google for it :)

Comment: Can you set breakpoints running from a dump file? This issue does not occur on my pc. Only on the newer pcs running windows 10 20H2.

Comment: A dump file is a snapshot for the current state. There is nothing in it that allows you to move back to when a memory write occurred. For that you would need something like [Time Travel Debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/time-travel-debugging-overview) (which is awesome in its own right).

Comment: I would try adding trace messages instead of breakpoints, to find where exactly the crash occurs. From the call stack info it seems that the crash occurs in some window procedure call. Add some more diagnostic code to find if `pWnd` is indeed the `CDevice` dialog or another window instead. Also, check the values of the message-ID and its parameters, these can help too.